# How to reference other collections in postman

Tags: postman

Is there a way to reference other collections from a specific collection. For example, if I have a file upload collection (something that uploads a file), I want to be able to use that from other collections. How would I reference the file upload?

Here's an example of what I'm talking about.

I have a collection where a file is uploaded and a calculation needs to be performed. The test or collection would go something like this where each step is a POST, GET, etc

Upload and run calculation:

1. Generate a token

   - make call
   - copy/save token value
2. Upload specific file (these would be 3 individual requests)

   - Upload file
   - Monitor upload status
   - Return ID of file uploaded
3. run calculation

   - use ID to pass as parameter
   - pass other values to set up calculation
   - monitor run
   - validate results

In another collection I need to validate uploaded files metadata is correct. Not directly related to the one above, but has some similarities

1. Generate a token

   - make call
   - copy/save token value
2. Upload specific file (these would be 3 individual requests)

   - Upload file
   - Monitor upload status
   - Get final result and return ID of file uploaded
3. Get me

   - validate metadata is correct.

Steps 1 and 2 are common functionality, there would be no difference there. How could I extract those two steps as modular components or functionality so I can reference them from any collection?

For additional clarity, we use ReadyAPI and are able to do 'Run Test Case' which can obviously run another test case. We've separated the functionality of token and file uploads into it's own test case and use it as a modular component. I'd like to achieve something similar with Postman.

Comment: Can you provide more information on how "to use that from other collections"?

Comment: @shaochuancs I've included a lot more information.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Postman collections are working a little bit different.

But you can Merge your two collections to a single one, and execute it as one single collections.

Comment: I've updated my use case if that helps clear things up. You may be touching upon what I'm looking for. I suppose what I don't know how to do is call the different collections?